# $f,g\in L^6(\mathbb R^n) \Rightarrow f\cdot g \in L^3(\mathbb R^n)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis

How can I proove:

$f,g\in L^6(\mathbb R^n) \Rightarrow f\cdot g \in L^3(\mathbb R^n)$

---

It doesn't seem like hard task but I don't even have ideas to present. Maybe I can't see the forest because of so many trees?

Comment: Do you mean $L^6(\Bbb R^n)$ and $L^3(\Bbb R^n)$?

Comment: Sorry, yes, that's what I meant. Strange, it seems that typo was also made on the sheet that task is on...

Comment: Are you aware that this is equivalent to $F, G \in L^2 \implies FG \in L^1$? Which is related to a famous inequality. (Assuming that the question is about [$L^p$ spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Lp_spaces_and_Lebesgue_integrals).)

Comment: Holder's inequality (also Cauchy–Bunyakovsky's inequality works here). Notice that $|f|^3$ and $|g|^3$ are in $L_2$ Hence $\int |fg|^3\leq \Big(\int|f|^6\Big)^{1/2}\Big(\int|g|^6\Big)^{1/2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$
\int |fg|^3 = \int |f|^3|g|^3 \leq \left(\int (|f|^3)^2\right)^{1/2} \left(\int (|g|^3)^2\right)^{1/2} = \left(\int |f|^6\right)^{1/2} \left(\int |g|^6\right)^{1/2}
$$